# Android - App Freezes While Activity Loads On Button Click

Tags: android

There's a button b0 which changes the Activity on click. However, the next activity a1 has to make a TCP connection with an ip address before starting!

Therefore, when the button b0 is clicked, the app freezes for about 3seconds then the other activity is loaded. How can I make a progress dialog while that happens?

In Activity a1

```
  public A1Activity() {
      // make a TCP connection to an ip address
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
       super.onCreate(bundle);
       setContentView(R.layout.pilot);
       // use the TCP connection
  }
```

Comment: How did you tried to initiate tcp connection?? In another thread?

Comment: @SujithNiraikulathan no. because it has to be done before the Activity is actually shown

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be to load the tcp connection in another thread, but in different place. Load socket connection in separate service and bind it to your activity "A". When you click button to open another activity, dont open the activity and tell the socket in the service to start and show some progress loader. Once connection established unbind service, dismiss progress and navigate to next activity "B". Now bind the service to the new activity "B".